# Question Saga: The Quest for Questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I realize this is a beta site, but [I came across this post](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/finding-freelance-bloggers-in-specialized-field). Which superficially seems fine to me… Except for the comment [from the original poster](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/finding-freelance-bloggers-in-specialized-field#comment3973_2366) which reads:

> I've split the question into four parts: i. Finding them, ii. Spotting
>   good ones, iii. Compensation & iv. Management

This kind of meta-self-tagging seems bad & not in line with the quality/behavior of posts I see on the Stack Exchange sites. Is it? Or am I overreacting?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing up this issue. The current state of these posts is definitely not perfect, largely due to the repetitive content, but the original was actually all one single post. We suggested that the asker focus on one question at a time to make it easier to focus answers.

I fixed the titles, which also contained the same meta-style markers. However, at the time, it wasn't immediately clear how to handle the fact that some of the content is duplicated in all four questions.

It looks like the first question got an answer that seems to also address some of the other questions, so it may be wise to merge them back into fewer posts.

The other thing we can do is leave a comment on the unanswered questions and see if the asker can come back and differentiate them a bit, which may help get those posts some answers.

Comment: But the question also raises the point: Those questions seem like headhunting questions. Which personally I find useless. I am here as someone who has freelanced & exploring options to freelance again. Tips on how to hire a staffer seem like a workplace question.